# Returning the most recent date when INDEX MATCH has multiple matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an index match formula which goes through a list and returns a date based on an email address. My issue I have is what if there are multiple entries that match that email address? How do I return the most recent date?

e.g. worksheet 1  has all the data

```
  A            B            C                 
email         ID            date
```

worksheet 2 has a list of specific email addresses i'm looking for info on

```
A         B
email   date
```

My formula in column B of worksheet 2 is along the lines of this:

`index(worksheet1 C:C,match(worksheet2 A1, worksheet 1 A:A,false))`

Basically saying where you find the email address in A1 listed in column A of worksheet 1, return in B1 the value in the column of that row in worksheet1.

The thing is we could have the same email address listed a number of times, so I'm looking for the latest date to be returned, not the first one it finds.

Thanks
simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using *DMAX Function*
`=DMAX(Sheet1!A1:C5,3,A1:A2)`

**Worksheet1:**
[image: Worksheet1]

**Worksheet2:**
[image]

[Here's more on DMAX Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dmax-function-HP010342451.aspx).
If however you have a lot of emails in sheet 2 that you want to look-up, another approach is needed.

If that is the case, you can try this *Array Formula*.
`=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:A$5=A3,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5))`
Above formula is entered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in Cell B2 as shown below.

**Result:**
[image]

As you can see, it has the same result as the *DMAX*.
But you can copy and paste or auto-fill this formula to succeeding cells in B.

Comment: I have hundreds of emails to lookup in sheet 2, and thousands in sheet 1

Comment: @user3720981 You can have a look on my edit. :D Btw, you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't realise there would be an difference based on the numbers involved. Based on a small sample that have been manually verified, your edit has done the trick :) Thanks alot!

Comment: @user3720981 It always does. Especially we're trying to help you on specific issues you are trying to solve.